# Not able to replace the wordpress plugin on google cloud through filezilla

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I am running wordpress instance on google cloud, when I try to upload plugin files it gives an error " Permission denied" 
I went to the google gloud SSH and gave the permission 777 to the folder in which I'm uploading the plugin but still getting failed.
what should be the reason for that ? (it's a wordpress plugin which I want to update)

Comment: It might be spammy or contains such code lines, that are blocked by google or SSL if you are using it. Try consulting it with plugin developer.

Comment: Have you tried using Google's tool for updating plugins? https://cloud.google.com/php/tutorials/wordpress-app-engine-flexible#updating_wordpress_plugins_and_themes

Comment: Try changing the folder owner to `www-data:www-data`, then add your user to the `www-data` group through [`usermod`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod)